# Подключение дополнительной логики к серверу

Tags: python, eel

<sub>*Библиотека [EEL](https://pypi.org/project/Eel/)*</sub>

```py
eel.init("web")
eel.start("/login.html")
```

В первом приложении запустил сервер и открыл страницу "login.html", второе приложение будет писать лог на этой же странице используя JS хранящейся в ней. Например:

```py
eel.log_indo_("СООБЩЕНИЕ ИЗ ПОДПРОГРАММЫ 2")
```

Как подключиться к созданному серверу?

ПЕРВОЕ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ

```
   import eel
   eel.init(web)
   eel.start("/login.html", block=False)

   while True:
       print("I'm a main loop")
       eel.sleep(1.0)
```

ВТОРОЕ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ

```
   import eel
   eel.init(web)
   

   while True:
       eel.log_indo_("СООБЩЕНИЕ ИЗ ПОДПРОГРАММЫ 2")
       eel.sleep(1.0)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.